# Display activity indicator on TableView with async programming - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I've been trying to figure this out now for a while.  I think I've pretty much exhausted all research options, so I'm putting it out to you, SO peeps.

I have a table view that segues to a web view.  The web view draws a map, sometimes with thousands of coordinates, so loading time can sometimes be somewhat long, obviously depending on the user's device.  So I want to plug in an activity indicator to let the user know the app hasn't crashed.

So I created the activity indicator programmatically, and set it to activate on didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  The problem here is that the indicator doesn't start showing until the task is finished - and what is the point of the indicator then.  So I gather that the solution here is to do this asynchronously, but the solution I've tried has no effect.  I tried plugging the code in the prepareForSegue function as well, but that's even worse - it segues to the map view before the data is loaded, thus displaying a blank map.

Any help here?  Below is my code.  Thanks!

```
class MapSelect: UITableViewController {

    let subdivisionArray = [There's an array here]

    let selectionArray = [There's an array here]

    let model = Model()
    var myView = UIView()
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

        myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height))
        myView.backgroundColor=UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
        myView.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.myView.alpha = 0.5
        })
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width / 2, self.tableView.frame.size.height / 2)
        self.tableView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        self.stopSpinner()


    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return subdivisionArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
        cell.textLabel?.text = subdivisionArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if subdivisionArray[indexPath.row] != "County" {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("toMapSelect2", sender: self)
        } else {

            self.spinner()

            let seconds = 0.1
            let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
            let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
            dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMapView", sender: self)

            })
            self.stopSpinner()

        }

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { ... }

    func spinner() {
        myView.hidden = false
        myView.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.myView.alpha = 0.5
        })
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        activityIndicator.hidden = false
    }

    func stopSpinner() {
        myView.hidden = true
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.hidden = true
    }

}
```

Here also is the code that loads the map to the web view in a separate "MapView class":

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        do {
            if prevSelectionType == "ed" {
                prevSelectionLabel = prevSelection
                prevSelection = model.decodeElectionDistrict(prevSelection)
            } else {
                prevSelectionLabel = prevSelection
            }

        }

        var regionEds : Array<String> = Array<String>()

        do {
            var pred : NSPredicate
            pred = NSPredicate(format: "region = %@", "")
            if prevSelectionType != "county" {
                if prevSelectionType != "ed" {
                    pred = NSPredicate(format: "region = %@" , prevSelection)
                } else {
                    pred = NSPredicate(format: "ed = %@" , prevSelection)
                }
                requestPick3.predicate = pred
            }
            requestPick3.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
            requestPick3.propertiesToFetch = ["ed"]
            requestPick3.returnsDistinctResults = true
            let resultsPre = try context.executeFetchRequest(requestPick3)
            for result in resultsPre {
                let resultEd : String = result["ed"] as! String
                regionEds.append(resultEd)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }

        self.mapView.delegate = self

        var dCoords : Array<Double> = Array<Double>()
        var twdString : String = String()
        var query : PFQuery = PFQuery()
        do {
            if prevSelectionType != "county" {
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"twd IN %@", regionEds)
                query = PFQuery(className: "Coords2016", predicate: predicate)
            } else {
                query = PFQuery(className: "Coords2016")
            }
            query.limit = 1000
            let userArray = try query.findObjects()
            //            print(userArray)
            for item in userArray {
                dCoords = item["coords"] as! Array<Double>
                twdString = item["twd"] as! String
                twdString = model.twdToEdAbbrev(twdString)
                addBoundry(dCoords, twd: twdString)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }

        // DEFINE CENTER LOCATION
        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: centerLat, longitude: centerLong)

        // DEFINE ZOOM SIZE
        centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)

        toggleSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: why not put the indicator to your MapView? And in your MapViewController, hide the webview first, show the indicator, and after the webview finish load, show it and hide the indicator.

Comment: I would definitely go for that solution if I could (and maybe I can, if I can figure it out).  The problem is that the screen stalls on the tableview while crunching the coordinate data - and I'm not exactly sure why that is, since all of that work is done in the MapViewController.

Comment: can you post your webview code as well, just the part to load the url. I think  you can try to put the load url part to viewDidAppear of your MapView controller.

Comment: OK, I posted the relevant part of the webview code.  It doesn't call on any url.  It starts with a query to core data, and then makes a call to parse.com for the actual coordinates.

Comment: you can try to move the codes in viewDidLoad to a background thread, it looks like the code block the UI. I think you can put some code to figure out how much time it takes to execute the codes for viewDidLoad, and if it really takes too much time that block the UI, you then try to find solution for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is that you start the spinner, and then stop it again almost immediately, and certainly before any of the work has completed

you need to put all of the work into a background queue, but everything that updates the UI needs to be done in the main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.spinner()
})
```

and then later

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.updateMapInSomeWay()
})
```

If you do it like that, you don't need to mess about with 0.1s delays before you start

Here's a good tutorial to get you started on background processing http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial